# Covariance of sum and maximum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution, covariance

I have the task :)

$X_1, X_2$ are independent and have uniform distribution on $(0,1).$ Calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1+X_2,\max(X_1,X_2))$.

I did it in this way.
The distriburion of $\max(X_1,X_2)$ is $P(\max(X_1,X_2)=x)=2x$ on $(0,1)$. In this way we have:
$E(X_1+X_2)\cdot E\max(X_1,X_2)=1 \cdot \frac{2}{3}$

\begin{align}
& E((X_1+X_2) \cdot \max(X_1,X_2))=2 E(X_1\cdot \max(X_1,X_2)) \\[6pt]
= {} &2 \cdot  \int_0^1 E(t \cdot \max(t,X_2))\cdot f_{X_1}(t) \,dt=2\cdot  \int_0^1 t \cdot \frac{t+1}{2} \, dt=\frac{5}{6}
\end{align}

So the covariance is equal $\frac{1}{6}$

But I have the correct answer to this task and it is $\frac{1}{12}$

Where did I mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have a continuous distribution your expression $P(\max(X_1,X_2)=x)=...$ does not make much sense. Evaluate $P(\max(X_1,X_2)\leq x)=P(X_1\leq x,X_2\leq x)=P(X_1\leq x)^2=x^2$ for $x\in(0,1)$ by iid assumption, $0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x>1$.

Comment: Thanks for correct. But density is ok and it is equal 2x on (0,1)

Comment: @John1357 I don't think the way you write density is ok, as the probability that your continuous distribution receive a value $P(\max(X_1,X_2)=x)$ is $0$. You should write $f_{\max(X_1, X_2)} (x) = 2x$ instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact $\Pr(\max\{X_1,X_2\}=x) = 0.$ I assume you must have meant that the value of the probability **density** function of $\max\{X_1,X_2\}$ at $x$ is $2x.$

$$
\operatorname E(\max\{t,X_2\}) = \operatorname E(\operatorname E(\max\{t,X_2\} \mid \mathbf 1[X_2>t]))
$$
where $\mathbf 1[X_2>t] = 1$ or $0$ according as $X_2>t$ or not.
$$
\operatorname E(\max\{t,X_2\} \mid \mathbf 1[X_2>t]) = \begin{cases} t & \text{if } X_2\le t, \\ (1+t)/2 & \text{if } X_2 > t. \end{cases}
$$
And the expected value of that is
\begin{align}
& t\cdot\Pr(X_2\le t) + \frac{1+t} 2\cdot\Pr(X_2>t) \\[8pt]
= {} & t^2 + \frac{1+t} 2\cdot(1-t) = \frac{1+t^2} 2 .
\end{align}

Comment: I see where I did mistake :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of your logic for calculating $\operatorname E\left[X_1\max(X_1,X_2)\right]$.

By definition, this is equal to

\begin{align}
\operatorname E\left[X_1\max(X_1,X_2)\right]&=\iint x\max(x,y)f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
\\&=\iint x\max(x,y)\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
\\&=\iint x^2\mathbf1_{0<y<x<1}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy+\iint xy\,\mathbf1_{0<x<y<1}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
\\&=\int_0^1\int_y^1 x^2\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy+\int_0^1 y\int_0^y x\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Set $X:=\max(X_1,X_2)$. Notice from symmetry $$\operatorname{cov}(X_1+X_2,X)=\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X)+\operatorname{cov}(X_2,X)=2\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X)$$ Let's take a closer look at $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X)$. First notice $E(X_1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and
$$E(X)=\int_0^1xf_X(x)\,dx=\int_0^12x^2\,dx=\frac{2}{3}$$ Therefore

$$\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X)=E(X_1X)-E(X_1)E(X)=E(X_1X)-\frac{1}{3}$$ From the total law of expectation, $$E(X_1X)=E(X_1X\mid X_1 \leq X_2)P(X_1 \leq X_2)+E(X_1X\mid X_1>X_2)P(X_1>X_2)$$ Notice $P(X_1 \leq X_2)=P(X_1>X_2)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $$E(X_1X\mid X_1 \leq X_2)=E(X_1X_2\mid X_1 \leq X_2)=\int_0^1\int_{x_1}^1\frac{x_1x_2}{P(X_1 \leq X_2)}\,dx_2\,dx_1=\frac{1}{4}$$ On the other hand, $$E(X_1X\mid X_1 > X_2)=E(X_1^2\mid X_1 > X_2) = \int_0^1 \int_{x_2}^1 \frac{x_1^2}{P(X_1 > X_2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2=\frac{1}{2}$$ We get that $E(X_1X)=\frac{1}{2}\big[\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\big]=\frac{3}{8}$ which means $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X)=\frac{1}{24}$ and finally $$\operatorname{cov}(X_1+X_2,X)=\frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

A geometric approach (considering only the half square $0 \le X_1 \le X_2 \le 1$ because of symmetry)

[image: Unif_max&sum_1]

clearly shows that the joint pdf is
$$
p(m,s) = 2\left[ {m \le s \le 2m} \right]
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
and which in fact gives
$$
\eqalign{
  & \int_{m = 0}^1 {\int_{s = 0}^2 {p(m,s)\,dm\,ds} }  = 2\int_{m = 0}^1 {\int_{s = m}^{2m} {\,dm\,ds} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\int_{m = 0}^1 {mdm}  = 1 \cr} 
$$

Then
$$
\eqalign{
  & \overline m  = 2\int_{m = 0}^1 {m^{\,2} dm}  = {2 \over 3}  \cr 
  & \overline s  = 2\int_{m = 0}^1 {\int_{s = m}^{2m} {\,dm\,sds} }  = 3\int_{m = 0}^1 {m^{\,2} dm}  = 1 \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & 2\int_{m = 0}^1 {\int_{s = m}^{2m} {\,\left( {m - 2/3} \right)\left( {s - 1} \right)dm\,ds} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\int_{m = 0}^1 {\left( {m - 2/3} \right)dm\int_{s = m - 1}^{2m - 1} {\,s\,ds} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{m = 0}^1 {\left( {m - 2/3} \right)\left( {3m^{\,2}  - 2m} \right)dm}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{m = 0}^1 {\left( {3m^{\,3}  - 4m^{\,2}  + 4/3m} \right)dm}  =   \cr 
  &  = {3 \over 4} - {4 \over 3} + {4 \over 6} = {1 \over {12}} \cr} 
$$